# Laravel Run function from console command

Tags: laravel, controller, console, command, execute

LARAVEL 5.2, just created the command named "HelloWorld" and here is the code:

```
 <?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use App\Http\Controllers\HelloWorldController;

class MakeImportsCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'helloworld';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Say Hello World Controller';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        return $this -> helloWorld();

    }
}
```

My controller *HelloWorldController.php* looks as below:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HelloWorldController extends Controller
{
    public function helloWorld() {
        echo 'Hello World from controller';
    }

}
```

My Kernel.php has following commands so far:

```
protected $commands = [
        Commands\Inspire::class,
        Commands\HelloWorldCommand::class,
    ];
```

When I run the controller VIA Routing method it works, but I want to run this via Console command. Here is my command on console : php artisan helloworld . And I get the error :

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]Call to undefined method App\Console\Commands\HelloWorldCommand::helloWorld()
```

My question is: Is there any way to call this function VIA command console? How? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved! 
I've just placed on handle controller's class name and called the function as following:

```
$x = new HelloWorldController(); 
echo $x->helloWorld();
```

It worked!